# Non-repository management of TeXLive packages on Ubuntu

Tags: beamer, texlive, ubuntu

I am looking to update my version of `beamer` to 3.10 (which supports nonstandard slide aspect ratios), however the Ubuntu main repository only has version 3.07. I was not able to locate `tlmgr`. Is there some other repository that I can include in synaptic to get the latest versions of packages or some other way to manage packages short of manually replacing files?

Further information:

`TeXLive 2009-10` on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Is that last line supposed to be a link?

Comment: No, that's the version of TL and Ubuntu I currently have installed.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ubuntu (and many other Linux distributions) repackages TeX Live without `tlmgr`, the idea being that the Linux package manager is then in charge of what gets installed. Unfortunately, they also ship a rather old TeX Live (currently TeX Live 2009 when the release version is TeX Live 2010). So there is no way to install updated packages using the system as set up by Ubuntu. You'll need to either (1) do a local installation of `beamer` or (2) [install TeX Live 2010 outside of the Ubuntu package manager](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).

Comment: I'd forgotten that question!  I was just effectively typing out my answer to that question again when your answer appeared.  Just to add that installing TeX Live 2010 outside of the Ubuntu package manager works absolutely fine (Option 3 in my answer to your linked question) and is very easy to do.

Comment: @Andrew: I guess somewhere on {TeX} there's a good link for the first method (local installation), but I couldn't find an ideal one. Do you know of one?

Comment: @Joseph: I don't know of one, do we want one?  I presume that this is well-covered by the TUG/TeX FAQ sites.  I suppose that there's no harm in duplication.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I suspected it would come down to this. Oh well, I think Andrew Stacey's option 3 will be best in the long term. Thanks for your time. *starts download*

Comment: Note that I created a bug report on the outdated TeXLive in Ubuntu. It would be great if you could mark it as affecting you and subscribe to it, maybe also leave a comment. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521

Comment: @Ingo Gerth: This no longer affects me as I am currently using non-repository TeXLive, which I consider to be the optimal solution. Whilst I am certainly not averse to TL2010 being in the repository, the real problem is not the absence of TL2010 but the inertia of the repository, of which the absence of TL2010 is a symptom. Even then, the TL metapackage in the repository is rather monolithic and frozen in time whereas `tlmgr` allows finer subpackage control and faster updates. This said, I will add my voice to the bug report when I get time as it's still a good idea. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interested in a newer version of beamer, you can also install beamer in your home directory (I believe the default path under Ubuntu is `~/texmf`). See Section 2.3 of the [beamer user manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Debian has latex-beamer for 2.10 in unstable. You could rebuild it on your machine, or possibly just install the binary directly. (See [Debian latex-beamer package page](http://packages.qa.debian.org/l/latex-beamer.html)  for more information. Click on the unstable version on the left for downloads.) It doesn't have much by way of dependencies. It is also possible that some more recent version of Ubuntu has 2.10. You didn't specify which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Also, building or updating Debian/Ubuntu packages is not really that hard, if you are willng to do a little work.

```
# apt-cache policy latex-beamer
latex-beamer:
  Installed: 3.07-2
  Candidate: 3.07-2
  Version table:
     3.10-1 0
         50 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ unstable/main i386 Packages
 *** 3.07-2 0
        500 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Package: latex-beamer
[...]
Version: 3.10-1
Depends: pgf (>= 1.00-1), latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1), texlive-latex-base
```