# How can I manually install a LaTeX package (Debian/Ubuntu Linux)?

Tags: macros, packages, installing, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

The Debian/Ubuntu archives typically include assemblies of many LaTeX packages for convenience of downloading (e.g., [texlive-latex-extra](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/texlive-latex-extra)). However, a user may prefer a single package to these conglomerations. Is there a simple way to manually acquire a single LaTeX package on Debian/Ubuntu?

Comment: Debian includes a `texlive-full` package. If you don’t want to worry about such things, install this one.

Comment: Closed as a 'reverse dupe': we've now got a proper answer for the general case.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The following four steps permit manual installation of packages on Debian/Ubuntu (and presumably other Linux) systems.

1. Download the package from CTAN (e.g., [footmisc.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc.zip)).
2. Extract the files and place them in an appropriate directory (e.g.,
   `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/footmisc/`). This location is
   preferable to the main installation tree
   (`/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/`) as the files are more likely
   to be preserved during upgrades.
3. Generate the `.sty` file by running `latex` on the appropriate source
   files (e.g., `latex footmisc.ins` and `latex footmisc.dtx`).
4. Update the `ls-R` file in this source tree (e.g., `cd
   /usr/local/share/texmf/ ; sudo mktexlsr`). Because
   `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/` is not searched recursively by
   kpathsea (cf. `kpsepath tex`), the `ls-R` file at the root directory
   of this search path must be updated to make the system aware of the new
   package.

Comment: What happens if the manually installed package (in the "preferable" `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/YouNameIt` directory) gets, also, available in the repositories and installed automatically during an upgrade to the main installation tree? Any confusions to be expected?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex` normally takes precedence over `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex`. Check the output of `kpsepath tex`.

Comment: @mph Indeed, it precedes.

Comment: there is no tex folder in texmf in my system as you mentioned in point 2. how do i proceed ?

Comment: @Hirak, create those folders yourself.

Comment: Is there a difference between updating `ls-R` with `mktexlsr` and with `texhash`?

Comment: On my Fedora 23, I had to install it to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/texmf-compat/tex/latex`

Answer (score 11):

The `TeXLive` in the repositories is from 2009. It's more recommended to go with the latest version on the Tug (TeX Users Group) website:

http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

Once you have installed this, you'll have access to the command `tlmgr` which stands for 'TeX Live manager'. There have been a few other posts here on `tex.se` that will give further information:

- [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)
- [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu)

The advantage of using `tlmgr` is that it will keep all of the dependencies up to date- trying to do this manually can often be frustrating :)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. As of now, I prefer to stick with the Debian stable texlive (2009) because my system tends to have problems with more "bleeding edge" installs. Short of tlmgr, which I will look forward to in the next Debian stable release, is there another way to install a single package besides downloading it, moving files to appropriate locations (probably `/usr/local/`) and updating the ls-R files?

Comment: @user001: that should work, but as I say, there might be dependencies that are hard to predict :)

Comment: @user001 This is in some ways a Debian question as what you want to do is grab part of something they have packaged up. The 'pure TeX' way is to either use `tlmgr` as cmhighes says or to get it from CTAN as you suggest in your question.

Comment: TexLive fails to update tikz-cd, which I need.  I put it inside my ~/texmf directory, but how can I get it to work with TexLive?

Answer (score 3):

I always found that the easiest way to manually install a package is to create a folder texmf in my "home" directory, dump all the downloaded .sty or .cls or whatever in there and run texhash texmf. That's all I ever had to do, if I'm not installing a font.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I will try that as well. Does `texhash texmf` operate similarly to `mktexlsr`?

Comment: @user001: In Debian, `texhash` is simply a link to `mktexlsr`.

Comment: Don't you have to manually create an ls-R file? I've done the file dumping in `~/texmf`, but `texhash` doesn't create an ls-R file (it updates the ones at `/usr/share`, but LaTeX is still not seeing the package.

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @FlybyNight, it does. At least in Ubuntu/Debian it never failed. Please provide more info, as well as reasons to downvote the answer.

Comment: It seems not to work in debian installations, because the updated version of a package may have dependencies, which must then be installed etc. - and second, the structure of the texmf file seems to be very strict and files from packages must be correctly filed.