# Kile and Ubuntu 11.10 AND RevTeX

Tags: installing, kile, revtex, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a LaTeX package (Debian/Ubuntu Linux)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux)

I just downloaded RevTeX for a PRL paper that I propose to write. However, after unzipping the contents of the RevTeX folder, where should I copy/mv them? And do I need sudo rights for that?

I run Kile 2.1 and I am confused because I understand that I'd need to place my class style files in

```
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex
```

But files placed in it are somehow not found by kile and I get errors that "so-and-so style file wasn't found".

Should I change any latex specific environment variables file somewehre? Should I the permissions to any files with `chown` or `chmod`?

Comment: Run `sudo mktexlsr` for refreshing the filename database.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz  Right... it did _something_ but I don't know what. How should I go about installing my revtex packages? Just dump them in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex`?

Comment: I would put it to `/home/stefan/texmf/tex/latex/revtex/`, so it would survive an update of the OS or texlive and even a change to a TeX Live 2011 installation.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Thanks, I'll try that and see how it goes.