# Is there a library for drawing object inheritance trees in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

This seems like a very common thing, but searching for the words 'tree', 'language', 'object', 'inheritance' and/or 'parent' returns Questions that have nothing to do with mine.

**In a nutshell**, I want this:

[image: Inheritance Tree]

But if instead of class B-D I have B-V, I would rather not go in and manually move everything around. Currently, I am using nodes and my classes are flying off the page.

What is one/any way to tackle this problem.

**MWE:**

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,calc,shadows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        neuronModel/.style={%
            general shadow={%
                shadow scale=1,
                shadow xshift=0.75ex,
                shadow yshift=0.75ex,
                opacity=0.75,
                fill=black!50,
                every shadow
            },
            rounded corners,
            thick,
            draw=blue!90,
            fill=blue!35,
            thick,
            inner ysep=2pt,
            inner xsep=2pt
        }]

        % \foreach \neuronIndex/\neuronLabel in {1/Bidirectional Neuron Model , 10/Unidirectional Neuron Model}
            % \node at (\neuronIndex,10)[draw=black,fill=blue]{\neuronLabel};

        \node[neuronModel,align=center] (neuronModel1) {Bidirectional\\
                                                                                    Neuron Model};
        \node[neuronModel,right=0.5cm of neuronModel1,align=center] (neuronModel2) {Unidirectional\\
                                                                                    Neuron Model};
        \node[neuronModel,right=0.5cm of neuronModel2,align=center] (neuronModel3) {Postprocessing\\
                                                                                    Neuron Model};
        \node[neuronModel,right=0.5cm of neuronModel3,align=center] (neuronModel4) {Preprocessing\\
                                                                                    Neuron Model};
        \node[neuronModel,right=0.5cm of neuronModel4,align=center] (neuronModel5) {Stats\\
                                                                                    Neuron Model};
        \node[neuronModel,right=0.5cm of neuronModel5,align=center] (neuronModel6) {Visual\\
                                                                                    Neuron Model};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the resulting picture. I need to add about 5 more classes, so this approach will not suffice.

[image: Long inheritance diagram]

Comment: [Yes](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `tikz-qtree` package can probably do what you want. Here is a crude example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level distance=50pt}
\Tree [.\node[draw]{class A};
    [.\node[draw]{class B}; ]
    [.\node[draw]{class C}; ]
    [.\node[draw]{class D};
        \node[draw]{class E};
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As pointed out by Alan Munn, the code can be further simplified by specifying the node style in advance:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style=draw]
\tikzset{level distance=50pt}
\Tree [.{class A}
    [.{class B} ]
    [.{class C} ]
    [.{class D}
        {class E}
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Where did you download it from? This link is the best I could find, but even the README file doesn't provide and installation directions http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-qtree

Comment: @puk: What distribution are you using? I'm on TeXLive 2011 and `tikz-qtree` is part of it. i.e. I didn't have to download anything special for this.

Comment: This can be further simplified with [`every tree node/.style=draw`] added to the `tikzpicture` environment.  Then you don't need to make every label a node. (I.e. you can just do `[.{Class A} [.{Class B} ] [.{Class C} ] [.{Class D} [.{Class E} ]]]`

Comment: According to Ubuntu 11.10 (`apt-get install texlive-full`) it is installed and up to date. According to `pdflatex` the file `tikz-qtree.sty` can not be found.

Comment: `tikz-qtree` was first released at the very end of 2009 (effectively 2010); if the Ubuntu image isn't that recent then you are up-to-date with respect to the Ubuntu package, but not with TeXLive.  Most people solve this by installing their own version of TeXLive and not using the Ubuntu package manager.  See [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092). Alternatively, just install it locally: [How can I manually install a LaTeX package (Debian/Ubuntu Linux)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/)

Comment: @AlanMunn: I think I tried that once, but it lead to the node boxes being all uneven sizes...

Comment: @AlanMunn: It seems I was mistake. I'll add some code to the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt The boxes may end up different sizes, but that can be fixed with the `minimum height` etc. parameters in the style setting (as for any other nodes).