# LaTeX poker package

Tags: errors

I have downloaded [this](http://www.encke.net/UpDownload-req-viewdownloaddetails-lid-23-title-poker.sty...LaTeX.Poker.package.v0.81a.html) package that allows to me to include poker card symbols in my LaTeX document. I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux) post to install the new package, except that I installed the package into `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/poker`.
Following the doc inside the package I have tried to compile these few lines

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{poker}
\begin{document}
\begin{cards}
\crdAs 
\end{cards}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX localizes the package, but is unable to understand new commands

```
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/txfonts/ot1txr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \scaleboxto 
                   (\pkr@pvw ,\pkr@pvh ){\pkr@col \sf \pkr@val }
l.5 \crdAs
```

returning me weird output. Have I made some mistake? Where is the error?

```
>latex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0
Copyright 2009 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.46
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.3.4
Compiled with poppler version 0.18.2
```

Comment: The page you refer to says "switch from `\scaleboxto` to `\psscaleboxto`"; saying `\let\scaleboxto\psscaleboxto` after `\usepackage{poker}` may possibly solve the issue.

Comment: thanx for the tip, no more error during compilation but persisting weird output :(

Comment: After downloading the latest version from the site I get no error (there's no trace of `\scaleboxto` in the package)

Comment: How do you translate your file? The package uses PS-Tricks, so pdflatex may not work, you need latex.

Comment: I have tryied. Still weird output.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the latest version of `poker` seems to require a recent version of PSTricks; update your old and outdated TeX Live.

Comment: I had removed PSTrikcs and reinstalled from repositories, but still does not works. May be I have to download the latest source from project web site?