# How to install the chemfig.sty package under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu

I am using TexMaker on ubuntu 12.04 to edit my Latex-documents. Lately, I needed to create a chemical structure with 'chemfig'. However, this package is not included in the 'TexLive-all'-package and thus, I had to install it manually. Here's how I did it:

Comment: Possible Related/Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux?lq=1 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the required package online (for e.g. on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org)).
2. If it's zipped, unzip the archive to a place where it's easily accessible such as your desktop.
3. Open a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) and type: `sudo nautilus`
4. Hit enter and type in your password and confirm with enter.
5. This will open a window in which you have administrator-rights, meaning you can copy or move files in your system-directory.
6. In this window, navigate to `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex` and create a folder with the name of your package (for e.g. `Chemfig` if your package is called `chemfig.sty`).
7. Copy the files `chemfig.sty`, `chemfig.tex` and `t-chemfig.tex` to your freshly created folder and assure the files were really copied. If they weren't go back to step 3 and make sure you run the command correctly.
8. Open another terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and run the following command: **texhash**

You should now be able to use the package in your Latex-editor. If not, a restart should help.