# How to change PGF from 2.1 to 3.0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, installing

I am using TexLive 2011. Although I have downloaded PGF 3.0 and put it into the folder texmf but the `\ pgfversion` always result in 2.1.How to change PGF from 2.1 to 3.0?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Simple advice: Upgrade to TeX Live 2014. Many packages have had important updates in the last 3 years. If you are in doubt, you can install TL14 parallel to TL11, giving you the possibility to switch back and forth.

Comment: Also look here [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux) assuming you use linux.