# problems with moderncv after update

Tags: packages, texlive, moderncv

I am trying to install the latest 2.0.0 version of `moderncv`. I follow this [guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/how-can-i-manually-install-a-latex-package-debian-ubuntu-linux), but since all `.sty`-files are already in the downloaded `zip`, I only perform the last action: `cd /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex; sudo mktexlsr`.

When I run pdftex on the following MWE, I get the error shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{black} 

\name{Horse}{Horsey}
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2013--2016}{Ate grass on a field}{}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```

`Error: Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"`

The beginning of the log-file says:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.10.12)  1 FEB 2016 17:35
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**cv.tex
(./cv.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
```

What am I missing/doing wrong? I can't find anybody else with a similar problem, seems like moderncv works fine for everyone else.

Comment: Have you tried to compile with XeLaTeX instead if pdflatex?

Comment: @samcarter then I get the error `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \tiny \faCircleO`

Comment: mmm, than I am out of ideas.

Comment: Have you unzipped the contents of the package in your tex folder?
In my case it would be /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv (may vary according to your installation method and settings you chose). After copying your files there, did you run
'sudo texhash'?

Comment: The final solution was simply to re-install my texlive-distribution, now it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by reinstalling the TeX distribution.