# How to install minted in Ubuntu

Tags: installing, ubuntu, minted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

I'm very new to Latex and have understood basic concepts. Now I would like to get syntax highlighting. `minted` seems to be best choice according to Google but I you don't find detailed instructions on how to install it on a Ubuntu machine (and it is not included in any package).
I'm a bit stuck after generating the `minted.sty` file. What steps to take next?

Comment: See perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu

Comment: Did you notice the documentation file? It contains a fairly detailed installation instruction. If you’ve got stuck at a particular command, we can certainly help.

Comment: If you installed LaTeX from the repositories (e.g., using apt-get), then it is quite likely that you could copy the file to `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/` and then run the command `sudo texhash` in a terminal.  (Note that I've neither installed nor used `minted`.)  I recommend you look at the [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=inst-wlcf) for better/fuller advice.

Comment: Closed as a 'reverse dupe': we've now got a proper answer for the general case.

Comment: more hints. minted is inside package "texlive-latex-extra" in Ubuntu version - Quantal (12.10), while it doesn't exist in previous ubuntu release. Which you need install .sty directly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update for Ubuntu 20.04**: see [I can't get minted package to work under Ubuntu (pygments error)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563919/6621)

### old answer (not recommended, see above link)

- In Ubuntu `minted` is included in `texlive-latex-extra` package

  ```
    sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
  ```
- Or you can install `minted` manually, as mentioned in the comments.

[Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu)

Once you have `minted` installed (which comes by default with `TeXLive`), you'll need `python-pygments`

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygments
```

If you want to run your file with `pdflatex`, then you need to so with `shell-escape`

```
pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

The documentation has this, and more information.

```
texdoc minted
```

Comment: In addition to @jon 's comment it did the trick.

Comment: @phineas Glad it worked :) The TeXLive in the repositories is out of date- best to go with the instructions in the linked question.

Comment: After I did  what @cmhughes suggested my pdflatex stop working. Here is the error message: ktexpk: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1+37/600; nonstopmode; input tcit0800' failed.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file tcit0800): Font tcit0800 at 637 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!