# I can't get minted package to work under Ubuntu (pygments error)

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, minted

I'm currently using ubuntu13.10, TeXlive and Texmaker editor, and I found out that minted package is the best way to get source code highlighting on LaTeX.

So I installed `python-pygments` via terminal (`sudo apt-get install python-pygments`), it actually installed correctly, but when I start Texmaker and type `\usepackage{minted}` the log displays:

> ! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape
>   flag.
>
> ! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use
>   this packag e.

and it gives me this error as well:

> LaTeX Error: File `mytexts.pyg' not found.

I'd appreciate some help on that, I'm learning `C atm` and minted would be really helpful.

EDIT:

Mmm, I chek out tm settings>fast comp. and I have selected `latex + dvips + ps2pdf + see pdf` option, so I should add the -shell-escape line to dvips at settings>commands or to ps2pdf or both of them?

That's what I'm not really getting, where I should add the shell escape lines...

(python-pigments + texlive are already installed)

thanks

Comment: The first error message is quite clear. You need to add `-shell-escape` to the command line options for the compiler in your TeXmaker settings.

Answer (score 31):

with running `apt-cache search pygments` you'll get the needed packages:

```
voss@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache search pygments
python-pygments - syntax highlighting package written in Python
python-sphinx - documentation generator for Python projects (implemented in Python 2)
python3-pygments - syntax highlighting package written in Python 3
python3-sphinx - documentation generator for Python projects (implemented in Python 3)
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
python-django-debug-toolbar - Embedded debugging toolbar for Django projects
ruby-albino - Ruby wrapper for pygmentize
trac-wikiprint - Make Trac wiki pages printable, exporting to PDF or printable HTML
```

Install the package(s) with

```
voss@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pygments
```

and maybe that you also need to install the texlive package. Anf when everything is installed you need the `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` command

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.10, I needed `python3-pygments`

Comment: @Rasmus I found the same for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using TeXStudio under Ubuntu or other GNU/Linux distribution, the answer is simple,

1. Install Pygments: `sudo easy_install Pygments`
   (make sure you have python installed)
2. In TeXStudio Options > Configure TeXStudio > Completion > (select `minted` related packages)[`minted.cwl` etc] and press OK. If you can't find `minted` there, install it by yourseelf: go to http://code.google.com/p/minted/, download `minted`, unzip, run `latex minted.ins` and it will generate `minted.sty`; move the `sty` file to your desired location
3. After having installed/found `minted`, in the same TeXStudio window go to Commands and put  `-shell-escape`  in the PdfLaTeX/LaTeX compilation commands.

Answer (score 8):

I recently had the same problem in ubuntu 20.04 and solved it by installing Pygments (as  [rasmus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12558/rasmus) say)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygments
```

And, of course, adding `-shell-escape` in the configuration of the editor

Note: `sudo apt-get install python-pygments` didn't work