# Caption in wrapfigure spills into text

Tags: captions, wrapfigure

The caption in my wrapfigure spills into text. Is this fixable with wrapfigure or do I need to use something else?

Screenshot:

[image]

MWE (sorry for the mess in the preamble, but some of that is probably responsible):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, headinclude, twoside=false, parskip=half+, pagesize=auto, numbers=noenddot, plainheadsepline, open=right, toc=listof, toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
% eigene syntax highlighting
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{xcdraw}{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
% PDF-Kompression
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=1
% Allgemeines
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} % Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage{amsmath,marvosym} % Mathesachen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Ligaturen, richtige Umlaute im PDF
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% UTF8-Kodierung für Umlaute usw
% Schriften
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Palatino für Mathemodus
%\usepackage{mathpazo,tgpagella} % auch sehr schöne Schriften
\usepackage{setspace} % Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing % 1,5 Zeilen
% Schriften-Größen
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Huge\rmfamily} % Überschrift der Ebene
\setkomafont{section}{\Large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\large\rmfamily} % Überschrift der Ebene in Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\bfseries\rmfamily} % für description Umgebungen
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}
% Sprache: Deutsch
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Silbentrennung
% PDF
\usepackage[english,pdfauthor={Foo Bar},  pdfauthor={Foo Bar}, pdftitle={Report}, breaklinks=true,baseurl={http://www.bretschneidernet.de/tips/thesislatex.html}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % mikrotypographische Optimierungen
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % einzelne Seiten drehen können
% Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow} % Tabellen-Zellen über mehrere Zeilen
\usepackage{multicol} % mehre Spalten auf eine Seite
\usepackage{tabularx} % Für Tabellen mit vorgegeben Größen
\usepackage{longtable} % Tabellen über mehrere Seiten
\usepackage{array}
%  Bibliographie
%\usepackage{bibgerm} % Umlaute in BibTeX
\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\bibliography{bibliographie}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}} 
% Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow} % Tabellen-Zellen über mehrere Zeilen
\usepackage{multicol} % mehre Spalten auf eine Seite
\usepackage{tabularx} % Für Tabellen mit vorgegeben Größen
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
% Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx} % Bilder
\usepackage{color} % Farben
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg} % bevorzuge pdf-Dateien
\usepackage{subfigure} % mehrere Abbildungen nebeneinander/übereinander
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figurename} % um \autoref auch für subfigures benutzen
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} % Beim Klicken auf Links zum Bild und nicht zu Caption gehen
% Bildunterschrift
\setcapindent{0em} % kein Einrücken der Caption von Figures und Tabellen
\setcapwidth[c]{0.9\textwidth}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0.2cm} % Abstand der zwischen Bild- und Bildunterschrift
% Quellcode
\usepackage{listings} % für Formatierung in Quelltexten
\definecolor{grau}{gray}{0.25}
\lstset{
    extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    %basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    tabsize=2,
    keywordstyle=\textbf,
    commentstyle=\color{grau},
    stringstyle=\textit,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    % für schönen Zeilenumbruch
    breakautoindent  = true,
    breakindent      = 2em,
    breaklines       = true,
    postbreak        = ,
    prebreak         = \raisebox{-.8ex}[0ex][0ex]{\Righttorque},
}
% linksbündige Fußboten
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\typearea{14} % typearea am Schluss berechnen lassen, damit die Einstellungen oben berücksichtigt werden
% für autoref von Gleichungen in itemize-Umgebungen
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\saved@equation}{}
\let\saved@equation\equation
\def\equation{\@hyper@itemfalse\saved@equation}
\makeatother 

%tiefere nummerierung
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

% hier beginnt der eigentliche Inhalt
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.44\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{images/hdfs}
   \caption{\label{hdfs}Loooong caption foo bar foo bar foo bar fooooo.}
\end{wrapfigure}

\ref{hdfs} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the `caption` package and use

```
\caption{\label{hdfs} \protect\raggedright long caption.}
```

could be one possible solution.

Note this solution needs to mark `minted` out because it causes some conflict with `xcolor` and/or `listings`

Also note, packages related to Bibliographie are marked out to make a clean run with Pdflatex. However, keep hitting the enter key without marking them out still gets the same results though.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, headinclude, twoside=false, parskip=half+, pagesize=auto, numbers=noenddot, plainheadsepline, open=right, toc=listof, toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
% eigene syntax highlighting
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{xcdraw}{xcolor}
%\usepackage{minted}     %< --- need to mark this out to make a clean run
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig,caption}
% PDF-Kompression
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=1
% Allgemeines
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} % Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage{amsmath,marvosym} % Mathesachen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Ligaturen, richtige Umlaute im PDF
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% UTF8-Kodierung für Umlaute usw
% Schriften
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Palatino für Mathemodus
%\usepackage{mathpazo,tgpagella} % auch sehr schöne Schriften
\usepackage{setspace} % Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing % 1,5 Zeilen
% Schriften-Größen
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Huge\rmfamily} % Überschrift der Ebene
\setkomafont{section}{\Large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\large\rmfamily} % Überschrift der Ebene in Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\bfseries\rmfamily} % für description Umgebungen
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}
% Sprache: Deutsch
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Silbentrennung
% PDF
\usepackage[english,pdfauthor={Foo Bar},  pdfauthor={Foo Bar}, pdftitle={Report}, breaklinks=true,baseurl={http://www.bretschneidernet.de/tips/thesislatex.html}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % mikrotypographische Optimierungen
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % einzelne Seiten drehen können
% Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow} % Tabellen-Zellen über mehrere Zeilen
\usepackage{multicol} % mehre Spalten auf eine Seite
\usepackage{tabularx} % Für Tabellen mit vorgegeben Größen
\usepackage{longtable} % Tabellen über mehrere Seiten
\usepackage{array}
%  Bibliographie   %<-- need to mark this out to make a clean run
%\usepackage{bibgerm} % Umlaute in BibTeX
%\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{csquotes} 
%\bibliography{bibliographie}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}} 
% Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow} % Tabellen-Zellen über mehrere Zeilen
\usepackage{multicol} % mehre Spalten auf eine Seite
\usepackage{tabularx} % Für Tabellen mit vorgegeben Größen
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
% Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx} % Bilder
\usepackage{color} % Farben
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg} % bevorzuge pdf-Dateien
\usepackage{subfigure} % mehrere Abbildungen nebeneinander/übereinander
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figurename} % um \autoref auch für subfigures benutzen
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} % Beim Klicken auf Links zum Bild und nicht zu Caption gehen
% Bildunterschrift
\setcapindent{0em} % kein Einrücken der Caption von Figures und Tabellen
\setcapwidth[c]{0.9\textwidth}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0.2cm} % Abstand der zwischen Bild- und Bildunterschrift
% Quellcode
\usepackage{listings} % für Formatierung in Quelltexten
\definecolor{grau}{gray}{0.25}
\lstset{
    extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    %basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    tabsize=2,
    keywordstyle=\textbf,
    commentstyle=\color{grau},
    stringstyle=\textit,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    % für schönen Zeilenumbruch
    breakautoindent  = true,
    breakindent      = 2em,
    breaklines       = true,
    postbreak        = ,
    prebreak         = \raisebox{-.8ex}[0ex][0ex]{\Righttorque},
}
% linksbündige Fußboten
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\typearea{14} % typearea am Schluss berechnen lassen, damit die Einstellungen oben berücksichtigt werden
% für autoref von Gleichungen in itemize-Umgebungen
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\saved@equation}{}
\let\saved@equation\equation
\def\equation{\@hyper@itemfalse\saved@equation}
\makeatother 

%tiefere nummerierung
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

% hier beginnt der eigentliche Inhalt
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.44\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-A}
   \caption{\label{hdfs} \protect\raggedright Loooong caption foo bar foo bar foo bar fooooo.}
\end{wrapfigure}

\ref{hdfs} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

\end{document}


\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, headinclude, twoside=false, parskip=half+, pagesize=auto, numbers=noenddot, plainheadsepline, open=right, toc=listof, toc=bibliography]{scrreprt}
% eigene syntax highlighting
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{xcdraw}{xcolor}
%\usepackage{minted}
% PDF-Kompression
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=1
% Allgemeines
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} % Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage{amsmath,marvosym} % Mathesachen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Ligaturen, richtige Umlaute im PDF
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% UTF8-Kodierung für Umlaute usw
% Schriften
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Palatino für Mathemodus
%\usepackage{mathpazo,tgpagella} % auch sehr schöne Schriften
\usepackage{setspace} % Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing % 1,5 Zeilen
% Schriften-Größen
\setkomafont{chapter}{\Huge\rmfamily} % Überschrift der Ebene
\setkomafont{section}{\Large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\large\rmfamily} % Überschrift der Ebene in Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\bfseries\rmfamily} % für description Umgebungen
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}
% Sprache: Deutsch
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Silbentrennung
% PDF
\usepackage[english,pdfauthor={Foo Bar},  pdfauthor={Foo Bar}, pdftitle={Report}, breaklinks=true,baseurl={http://www.bretschneidernet.de/tips/thesislatex.html}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{microtype} % mikrotypographische Optimierungen
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdflscape} % einzelne Seiten drehen können
% Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow} % Tabellen-Zellen über mehrere Zeilen
\usepackage{multicol} % mehre Spalten auf eine Seite
\usepackage{tabularx} % Für Tabellen mit vorgegeben Größen
\usepackage{longtable} % Tabellen über mehrere Seiten
\usepackage{array}
%  Bibliographie
%\usepackage{bibgerm} % Umlaute in BibTeX
%\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage{csquotes} 
%\bibliography{bibliographie}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}} 
% Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow} % Tabellen-Zellen über mehrere Zeilen
\usepackage{multicol} % mehre Spalten auf eine Seite
\usepackage{tabularx} % Für Tabellen mit vorgegeben Größen
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
% Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx} % Bilder
\usepackage{color} % Farben
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg} % bevorzuge pdf-Dateien
\usepackage{subfigure} % mehrere Abbildungen nebeneinander/übereinander
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figurename} % um \autoref auch für subfigures benutzen
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} % Beim Klicken auf Links zum Bild und nicht zu Caption gehen
% Bildunterschrift
\setcapindent{0em} % kein Einrücken der Caption von Figures und Tabellen
\setcapwidth[c]{0.9\textwidth}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0.2cm} % Abstand der zwischen Bild- und Bildunterschrift
% Quellcode
\usepackage{listings} % für Formatierung in Quelltexten
\definecolor{grau}{gray}{0.25}
\lstset{
    extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    %basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    tabsize=2,
    keywordstyle=\textbf,
    commentstyle=\color{grau},
    stringstyle=\textit,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    % für schönen Zeilenumbruch
    breakautoindent  = true,
    breakindent      = 2em,
    breaklines       = true,
    postbreak        = ,
    prebreak         = \raisebox{-.8ex}[0ex][0ex]{\Righttorque},
}
% linksbündige Fußboten
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}

\typearea{14} % typearea am Schluss berechnen lassen, damit die Einstellungen oben berücksichtigt werden
% für autoref von Gleichungen in itemize-Umgebungen
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\saved@equation}{}
\let\saved@equation\equation
\def\equation{\@hyper@itemfalse\saved@equation}
\makeatother 

%tiefere nummerierung
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

% hier beginnt der eigentliche Inhalt
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.44\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-A}
   \caption{\label{hdfs} \protect\raggedright Loooong caption foo bar foo bar foo bar fooooo.}
\end{wrapfigure}

\ref{hdfs} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, I use minted quite a lot for syntax highlighting in Scala. Is there a way to keep that in?

Comment: I activate the minted package, but it gives me an error exactly like the error shown in this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146264/34618. Since I don't know what your system is, I will leave this infor to you.  Maybe it can provide some hints/idrections.

Comment: For MiKTeX, Windows this is the link -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108661/34618

Comment: Seems to have been a Linux or your pygments installation problem only, works fine with my Windows 7.
So thanks a lot, I can implement that in the real document now.

Comment: @HelmHammerhand -- After knowing you still need `minted`. I started to wonder why it will fail if minted is activated and after trying and trying, looking into log files I came to realize I did not install pygments, thinking maybe you have the same issue. Thus, searching this site and got those information. Good to hear that it works. Thank you very much for the feedback.