# \hyperref to a \label doesn't work ("empty destination key")

Tags: xetex, hyperref, cross-referencing, warnings

In one of my documents, I used the combination of `\label` with `\hyperref`. Now, I fail for some reason.

I included the package:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

Created a label somewhere in my text:

```
\label{key1}
```

And referenced it from the text:

```
\hyperref[key1]{there}
```

But xelatex gives me this:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Empty destination name,
(hyperref)                using `UNDEFINED' on input line 66.
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  Some text. \label{key1} Continuing.

  Some more text (\hyperref[key1]{goto}).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me. Pl. improve it to show the actual problem.

Comment: @HarishKumar - what version of xelatex do you have? I have "XeTeX 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2".

Comment: @HarishKumar - That MWE actually shows my problem (on my machine) - the compiler outputs that error message, and link does not work.

Comment: @Rogach: My Xetex version is : `This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2011.12.21)  23 APR 2012 13:55
entering extended mode`. Looks like you have to update your distro.

Comment: @HarishKumar - I'd like to, but it is the latest texlive release available in repositories - and I do not want to build all the deb packages by myself (not that I'm lazy, there are just too many of them :))

Comment: @HarishKumar - besides, I assume the people were able to do the linking even before version 2.3 - I just do not know how.

Comment: the repositories are out of date- your example works fine in the latest `texlive`. Please see Martin's answer to [best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu)- you don't need to build the deb packages yourself, `texlive 2011` comes with very easy executables that do all of the work

Comment: It seems a bug that has been around between 2008 and 2009. The example works with TeX Live 2007 and 2010, not with the version of those two years. However, `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` might be better for this application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `\label` can be attached only to sections or subsections (or some other environments, like figures). To be able to reference arbitrary points in text, I needed to define "phantom section":

```
\phantomsection
\label{key1}
```

Comment: What hyperref needs, for sure, is a "hook" or "target." However, TeX does not "attach" a `\label` directly to the place where the command is encountered but, rather, to the "item" it's designed to cross-reference -- an equation, the header of a section of a section, the caption of a figure, etc. If, though, you need to create a hyper-target to a `\label` that's not associated with a known target type, it's necessary to specify `\phantomsection` (which might better be called `\explicittarget`).

Comment: Since `hyperref` 2010/04/17 v6.80x this is no longer necessary. The target is initialized with `Doc-Start`, that is set at the begin of the document.

Answer (score 2):

The repositories are out of date- your example works fine in `texlive 2011` available at

http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Please see Martin's answer to [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu)

You don't need to build the deb packages yourself, `texlive 2011` comes with very easy executables that do all of the work for you. Once you have `texlive 2011` installed, you can update it using `tlmgr update --self --all`