# Problem compiling BibTeX bibliography with pdfLaTeX

Tags: bibtex, pdftex

I'm sure this is an amateur problem, but I can't seem to get my BibTeX bibliography to compile using `pdfLaTeX`. It worked before when I did `Latex->DVI->PDF`, but then I had to add some syntactic trees using `tikz-qtree`, which requires the document be compiled with `pdfLaTeX`. Now the bibliography doesn't compile. In the main document, I get a `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]` error. In the MWE, no errors come back, but only "References" appears in the PDF. I'm thinking I may be missing a package in the preamble, or one of the other packages in my thesis (`tikz`,  `tikz-qtree`, `expex`, `tipa`, `mathtools`, `caption`) may be causing the conflict. Deleting the `.aux` file, etc., and recompiling hasn't worked either. There are a few url links in the `.bib` file.
I should note that when I usually compile my bibliography using BibTeX I use the `LaTeX->DVI->PDF` method rather than `pdfLaTeX` and it usually works fine. 
Using `Kile` on `Ubuntu 11.10`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}


\begin{document}



\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apacann}
\bibliography{tewa_bib}


\end{document}
```

Here's the bibTeX contents, sorry I couldn't figure out how to upload it.

```
@book{dixon,
  author    = "Dixon, R.M.W.",
  year      = "2002",
  title     = "Australian {L}anguages: Their {N}ature and {D}evelopment",
  publisher = "New York: Cambridge University Press"
}

@article{harrison,
  author    = "Harrison, John P.",
  year      = "1910",
  title     = "A {B}rief {D}escription of the {T}ewa {L}anguage",
  journal   = "American Anthropologist",
  volume    = "12\textnormal{(2)}",
  pages     = "497--504"
}

@book{jackendoff83,
  author    = "Jackendoff, Ray",
  year      = "1983",
  title     = "Semantics and {C}ognition",
  publisher = "Cambridge, MA: The MIT Press"
}

@incollection{jackendoff96,
  author    = "Jackendoff, Ray",
  year      = "1996",
  title     = "The architecture of the linguistic--spatial interface",
  booktitle = "Language and {S}pace",
  volume    = "14\textnormal{(2)}",
  editor    = "Bloom, P. and Peterson, M. A. and Nadel, L. and Garrett, M. F.",
  pages     = "1--30"
}

@article{koopman,
  author    = "Koopman, Hilda",
  year      = "1977",
  title     = "Prepositions, {P}ostpositions, {C}ircumpositions, and {P}articles: The {S}tructure of {D}utch {PP}s"

}


@article{kroskrity78,
  author    = "Kroskrity, Paul",
  year      = "1978",
  title     = "Aspects of {S}yntactic and {S}emantic {V}ariation within the {A}rizona {T}ewa {S}peech {C}ommunity",
  journal   = "Anthropological Linguistics",
  volume    = "20\textnormal{(6)}",
  pages     = "235--257"

}

@article{kroskrity78a,
  author    = "Kroskrity, Paul",
  year      = "1978a",
  title     = "On the {L}exical {I}ntegrity of {A}rizona {T}ewa /-d\'i/: {A} {P}rincipled {C}hoice between {H}omophony and {P}olysemy",
  journal   = "International Journal of American Linguistics",
  volume    = "44\textnormal{(1)}",
  pages     = "24--30",

}

@article{kroskrity81,
  author    = "Kroskrity, P. and Healing, D.",
  year      = "1981",
  title     = "Coyote-{W}oman and the {D}eer {C}hildren ({A}rizona {T}ewa)",
  journal   = "Coyote Stories II",
  pages     = "119--128",
  publisher = "Chicago: University of Chicago Press"

}

@article{kroskrity85,
  author    = "Kroskrity, Paul",
  year      = "1985",
  title     = "A {H}olistic {U}nderstanding of {A}rizona {T}ewa {P}assives",
  journal   = "Language",
  volume    = "61\textnormal{(2)}",
  pages     = "302--328"

}

@incollection{svenonius10,
  author    = "Svenonius, Peter",
  title     = "Spatial {P} in {E}nglish",
  booktitle = "Cartography of Syntactic Structures",
  volume    = "6",
  year      = "2010",
  editor    = "Guglielmo Cinque and Luigi Rizzi",
  publisher = "Oxford University Press",
  howpublished = "\url{http://ling.auf.net/lingBuzz/000001}"

}

@article{kroskrity10,
  author    = "Kroskrity, Paul",
  year      = "2010",
  title     = "Arizona {T}ewa {K}iva {S}peech as a {M}anifestation of {L}inguistic {I}deology",
  journal   = "Pragmatics",
  volume    = "3\textnormal{(3)}",
  pages     = "297--309"

}

@book{martinez83,
  author    = "Martinez, Esther \& Povijua, Peter",
  year      = "1983",
  title     = "San {J}uan {P}ueblo {T}ewa {D}ictionary",
  publisher = "Portales, NM: Bishop Publishing Co.; A production of the San Juan Pueblo Bilingual Program"

}

@book{martinez84,
  author    = "Martinez, Esther", 
  year      = "1984",
  title     = "Tewa {T}ales",
  publisher = "Unknown Publisher"

}

@book{saeed,
  author    = "Saeed, John I.",
  year      = "1997", 
  title     = "Semantics",
  publisher = "United Kingdom: Blackwell Publishing"

}

@article{svenonius06,
  author    = "Svenonius, Peter",
  year      = "2006",
  title     = "The {E}mergence of {A}xial {P}arts",
  journal   = "Nordlyd: Troms\o{} Working Papers in Linguistics",
  volume    = "\textnormal{Special issue on adpositions}, 33 \textnormal{(1)}", 
  editor    = "Peter Svenonius \& Marina Pantcheva",
  pages     = "49--77",
  publisher = "Troms\o: CASTL",
  howpublished = "\url{http://septentrio.uit.no/index.php/nordlyd/article/view/85}"

}

@book{adger09,
  author    = "Adger, D. and Harbour, D. and Watkins, L. J.",
  year      = "2009",
  title     = "Mirrors and {M}icroparameters: Phrase {S}tructure {B}eyond {F}ree {W}ord {O}rder", 
  publisher = "New York: Cambridge University Press"

}

@article{harbour12,
  author    = "Harbour, D. and Watkins, L. and Adger, D.",
  year      = "2012",
  title     = "Information structure, discourse structure, and noun phrase position in {K}iowa", 
  journal   = "International Journal of American Linguistics", 
  volume    = "78\textnormal{(1)}", 
  pages     = "97--126"

}

@book{lewis09,
  author    = "Lewis, M. P. (ed.)", 
  year      = "2009", 
  title     = "Ethnologue: Languages of the World, Sixteenth edition",
  publisher = "Dallas, Tex.: SIL International",
  howpublished =  "Online version: \url{http://www.ethnologue.com/}"

}

@incollection{mithun92,
  author    = "Mithun, M.",
  year      = "1992",
  title     = "Is basic word order universal?",
  editor    = "Payne, D.",
  booktitle = "Pragmatics of {W}ord {O}rder {F}lexibility",
  pages     = "15--62",
  publisher = "Amsterdam and Philadelphia: John Benjamins"

}
```

Comment: This compiles fine here.  Your sample file contains no text before the bibliography.  Adding some text, gives no problem.  Adding `\usepackage{tikz}` gives no problem.

Comment: Silly question, but did you compile with pdfLaTeX? It won't work for me, I still get an empty page with "References" at the top. Maybe I'm doing it wrong? It should be compiled: pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex, right?

Comment: Does `bibtex` creat a file `.bbl`? If so, this file should contain the whole bibliography and it certainly should not be empty.

Comment: Yes, it does create a .bbl and it except for

    `\begin{thebibliography}{}`
    
    `\end{thebibliography}` 

it is blank.

Comment: I'm running Kile 2.1 as an editor, not sure if that answers your question. When I run it on the MWE, I get the warning ".tewa/bbl:3 Empty 'thebibliography' environment input line 3". The damning thing is that yesterday I got it to compile but now it won't behave.

Comment: pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0

Comment: Rather old. You should update. And the version of bibtex?

Comment: BibTeX 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0

Would you happen to know the terminal command for updating pdflatex?

Comment: Have a look to this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu) and to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). Help for updating please in a new question.

Comment: @khelke -- I have the same versions on my computer (Ubuntu 11.10) and your file and bibliography compile fine (lots of warnings in your `.bib` file, however).  I don't have `tikz-qtree` or `expex` to test with, however.  Loading the other packages you mentioned doesn't change anything.  I don't use `kile` either; have you tried doing this from the command line, and with all auxiliary files deleted?

Comment: Yes when I compile from the command line and open the pdf I get a "cannot open file" error but when I compile in Kile it works with no errors but the page is blank.

Comment: @khelke -- And what does the `.log` say?  Does the error recur if you delete any of the above packages?  Have you checked which packages you are loading by adding `\listfiles` to the preamble (and looking at the `.log`)?  It seems as though no one will be able to reproduce this problem, so you need to take extra troubleshooting steps, and report back here with further information.  What if you use a different `.bib` file?  It could be the `.tex` or `.bib` file has some funky encoding issues that may be making either `pdflatex` and/or your editor choke.