# How to install unicode-math on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)?

Tags: xetex, installing, texlive, ubuntu

I want to install `unicode-math` to use with XeLaTeX. I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS (because of some incompatibilities of later kernel versions with my HW).

Is there a way to install `unicode-math` package? I tried to install it through `apt-get install texlive-math-extra`, but it doesn't seem to be in that package.

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Hm, it's all soooo complicated. I will probably abandon it then.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/+bug/327235 suggests that it is missing from the packages.  Probably simpler to install your own texlive as suggested in the linked question.