# MetaUML: update to master branch version

Tags: metapost, metauml

I've got installed MetaPost (and MetaUML) automatically with my Tex editor but now I want to update it with the version available on Github in the master branch.
Didn't find anything relevant on internet about how to install MetaPost or MetaUML.
Can someone give me some advice? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04
Thanks.

Comment: For MetaUML you can download the repository from GitHub and copy the files into the directory of MetaUML on your system. With TeX Live that directory should be something like `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/metauml`.

Comment: You might have a look at the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28528/15036)

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 you probably just want to stick with the `texlive-metapost` and `texlive-metapost-doc` packages.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=metauml.

Comment: And [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/15036) in particular.