# \subfloat command from subcaption package doesn't produce bottom margin if used in table

Tags: tables, graphics, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to typeset a table of images.
If image inserted into cell with `\subfloat` (subcaption package included), resulting box will be w/o bottom margin, but top, left and right margins will be ok.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Sample Table}
  \label{tbl:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}{c} \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image1}} \end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}{c} \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image1}} \end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}{c} \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image1}} \end{tabular}
    \\\hline
    \begin{tabular}{c} \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}} \end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}{c} \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}} \end{tabular} &
    \begin{tabular}{c} \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}} \end{tabular}
    \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If `subcaption` package replaced with `subfig` the table looks good.

Is there any way to fix such behavior, since I can't use `subfig`?
Or maybe there is another way to do table with images?

**Update:** Thanks to Gonzalo Medina, I solved original problem. But I stuck with another one with that approach.
I'm trying to put titles in separate column:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sample Table}
  \label{tbl:sample1}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth+1em\relax}

    imeage 1 &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}            

    \\\hline\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth+1em\relax}

    imeage 2 &    
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}

    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But text in first column is aligned at bottom of cell. How to make text in title column to be centered?

Comment: Apparently your subfloats won't have a caption. Is this the case?

Comment: yes, subfloats must be w/o a caption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\subfloat` is not a command implemented in the `subcaption` package, so it won't be recognised by the package. If you want to use the `subcaption` package, you can use the either the `subtable` environment or the `\subcaptionbox` command. If your subimages don't need a caption, you can simply use `\includegraphics`.

In the following example I used the [tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package to buid the table with the six images. In the first case, the images won't have a caption: in the second case, each image will have its caption:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sample Table}
  \label{tbl:sample1}
  \tabulinesep =_1em^1em
  \everyrow{\tabucline[0.4pt]-}
  \begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}            
    \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}  &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}
  \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sample Table}
  \label{tbl:sample2}
  \tabulinesep =_1em^0.5em
  \everyrow{\tabucline[0.4pt]-}
  \begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}} &
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}} &
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}}            
    \\
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}  &
     \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}} &
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}
  \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `tabu` package, in order to achieve the same result, some manual adjustments will be needed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sample Table}
  \label{tbl:sample1}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth+1em\relax}
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}            
    \\ \hline\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth+1em\relax}
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}  &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sample Table}
  \label{tbl:sample2}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
     \hline\rule{0pt}{23pt}
     \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}} &
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}} &
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,height=0.15\textwidth]{image1}}            
    \\[5.5em] \hline\rule{0pt}{23pt}
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}  &
     \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}} &
    \subcaptionbox{text}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,height=0.15\linewidth]{image2}}
   \\[5.5em] \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You said:
"`\subfloat` is not a command implemented in the `subcaption` package".

But if I remove `\usepackage{subcaption}` command I'll get compilation error `Undefined control sequence` at '\subfloat' command.
So it seems that `subcaption` package defines '\subfloat' command. Or it just uses another package that defines that command?

Comment: @TheBug `\subfloat` is not defined in `subcaption`; it is defined in the `subfig` package which is incompatible with `subcaption`.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wrote my question not so clear. Code in question use only four packages: `inputenc`, `graphicx`, `caption` and `subcaption`. As you see `subfig` is not included. Which one of these four packages does introduce `\subfloat` command?

Comment: @TheBug: none. Compiling your example code in my system (TeX Live2011) produces the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.16     \begin{tabular}{c} \subfloat
                                     {\includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth,...`. Do you get something different?

Comment: Interesting... Code above compiled fine on my system. I'm using TeX Live 2009 (standard texlive package on Ubuntu 10.10). What version of `caption` and `subcaption` packages do you use?

Comment: @TheBug:  `caption.sty    2011/08/18 v3.2b Customizing captions (AR)`, `caption3.sty    2011/08/18 v1.3b caption3 kernel (AR)`, and `subcaption.sty    2011/08/18 v1.1a Adding subcaptions (AR)`.

Comment: so i have
`Package: caption 2009/10/09 v3.1k Customizing captions (AR)`
`Package: caption3 2009/10/09 v3.1k caption3 kernel (AR)`
`Package: subcaption 2008/08/31 v1.0b Adding subcaptions (AR)`
maybe that makes sense. i'll try to update packages from ctan and experiment with it.

Comment: @TheBug You should install TeX Live directly from TUG and not from the Ubuntu's repositories. There's a number of questions discussing the advantages; see, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13709/non-repository-management-of-texlive-packages-on-ubuntu/13710#13710 (with the obvious change of TeX Live2010 to the now available TeX Live2011).

Comment: Gonzalo, Is it possible to get same result w/o tabu package?

Comment: @TheBug: see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks that works. But I've got another issue when tried to fit your example to my needs. Please, take a look to update to the original question.