# How to separate glossary entries from section references in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color, glossaries

I have a document, a glossary and references. I am using the hyperref package to create hyperlinks

```
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = red,
        urlcolor  = green,
        citecolor = blue,
        anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
```

Apparently, linkcolor colors both glossary entries and Section / Table / Figure numbers in red.

Is there a way to split this? (Actually, I'd like blue for links and normal black for glossary entries.)

Comment: You can temporarily change the colors using \hypersetup (repeatedly).

Comment: What do you mean? Before each call to `\gls{}` ?

Comment: Yup.  See Talbot's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As from `glossaries` v4.08, the command that performs the actual hyperlink is `\glsdohyperlink`. The default definition is

```
\newcommand*{\glsdohyperlink}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}
```

When the hyperlinks are enabled with `\glsenablehyper`, the internal command that's used for the hyperlinks is set to `\glsdohyperlink`. (In earlier versions, it was set directly to `\hyperlink`.) This means that if you want to adjust the hyperlinks, you can redefine `\glsdohyperlink` and then use `\glsenablehyper` (rather than having to fiddle with internal commands.) For example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = red,
        urlcolor  = green,
        citecolor = blue,
        anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an
example~\cite{article-minimal}}}

\renewcommand*{\glsdohyperlink}[2]{%
 {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}}

\glsenablehyper

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}
\label{sec:sample}

A \gls{sample} entry in section~\ref{sec:sample}.

\printglossaries

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

This will work for the other glossary entry commands, such as `\glstext` or `\glslink`, but not for the links in the location lists. The above produces:

[image: image of document]

So the citation link is in blue, the cross-references (including location cross-references) are in red and the glossary entry links are in black.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't work for me though. I tried to copy the whole example but I get this error: `\glsdohyperlink` undefined ... What should I do?

Comment: I guess it's a version issue

Comment: @tuculuxu You need at least v4.08, so I'm guessing you have an older version installed.

Comment: Is there an easy way to update packages in ubuntu?

Comment: @tuculuxu `tlmgr` is the best way of updating package but it depends on how you installed the TeX distribution on ubuntu. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13710

Comment: Yep, I tried to use `tlmgr` but ubuntu bashes me saying the command is not found... Seems I have texlive installed (but I never really understood this), can't remember how I installed Kile... But I guess it's another question.