# Glossary Internal Link Colours

Tags: hyperref, color, report

So I'm writing a report and have included a glossary. I have internal link colours set to blue for referring to sections within the report but this carries over to the words in a glossary too which means my report is littered with lots of blue hyperlinked words... Is there a way to change the colour of these glossary links and not the section/chapter links. Apologies if my terminology is off.

```
% What I have tried so far
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true,    % Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue,    % Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue,    % Colour of internal links
  citecolor    = red      % Colour of citations
}
```

NOTE: Reference made is from an external .bib file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true,    % Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue,    % Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue,    % Colour of internal links
  citecolor    = red      % Colour of citations
}

% Glossary stuff
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\input{glossaries}

% Reference stuff
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\title{test}
\author{Example}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a test sentence to say \gls{pt}. I want to cite this sentence\cite{tutorial:eoline} with a random reference from the bib file.
Would I use "gls\{pruningtable\}" every time I want to say \gls{pt}. Or would I just say pruning table from then on?

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]
Is it conventional to replace every word with a "gls{term}" entry for every word I have?

Comment: Show a small but *complete* example, that makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298002/how-to-separate-glossary-entries-from-section-references-in-hyperref which is a bit newer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sure - I will do my best and edit the original post.

Comment: @Marijn the first link you shared gave me a solution! Thank you!